# GMSGroundOverlay image size

Tags: gmsmapview

I'm trying to figure out the allowed maximal size for images used with [GMSGroundOverlay](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/interface_g_m_s_ground_overlay). It seems to me that this has been working up to about iOS 16.4 with images of roughly 4000x4000 pixels but now with iOS 16.6 and iOS 17 I only can get it to display images that are about 1000x1000 pixels or lower. Is there a known limit?